# Please set buildPython to your Python executable path. error

Tags: python, android, android-studio, chaquopy

I am trying to make some code in python and run it in to android studio and I got this error. I don't know how to solve this.

**My main Activity**

```
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            if (!Python.isStarted()){
                Python.start(AndroidPlatform(this))
            }

            val python=Python.getInstance()
            val pyObject=python.getModule("myscript")

            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

                var searchPromt by remember {
                    mutableStateOf("")
                }

                var result by remember {
                    mutableStateOf("")
                }

                TextField(value = searchPromt, onValueChange ={
                    searchPromt=it
                })

                Button(onClick = {

                    val obj=pyObject.callAttr("main",searchPromt)
                    result=obj.toString()

                }) {
                    Text(text = "Generate")
                }

                Text(text = result)
            }


        }
    }
}
```

**My build.gradel**

```
    android {
    namespace 'com.example.textdetection'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.textdetection"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        python {
            buildPython "D:/setup/python/Python 2"
        }

        python{
            pip{
                install "transformers"
            }
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                python.srcDir "src/main/python"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}
```

**My Python file**

```
from transformers import pipeline

def main(prompt):

//Some code
```

**My Logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.textdetection, PID: 8647  
                                                                                               
com.chaquo.python.PyException: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers'
```

**Build error**

```
A problem occurred starting process 'command 'D:/setup/python/Python''. Please set buildPython to your Python executable path. See https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#buildpython.
```

I know it's probably to do with file path and pip but I don't know how to call pip block so please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

As it says [here](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#buildpython), `buildPython` should be the path to a Python executable, not a directory.

Comment: hey I tried this code "buildPython "D:/setup/python/Python 2/python.exe" " and still got error "Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugPythonRequirements'.
> Process 'command 'D:/setup/python/Python 2/python.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1" I dont know what is that. but thank you for your time

Comment: That's a different error message: it's now able to start Python, but the requirements installation is failing. There will be more details of the failure further up in the log. if you need more help with that, please create an entry on our [issue tracker](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues).